# Should we identify outliers from population prior to taking sample?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, outlier, data-science-model

I am revising undergrad statistics course via [this course](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/course-v1:OLI+ProbStat+Open_Jan2017/info), where i am learning techniques to pull out sample from population.

While ensuring that sample is a decent representative of the population, I am left with a question.

- Should we care about identification and rectification of outliers prior to taking sample from population ?

[Here](https://github.com/guptakvgaurav/prob_stats/blob/master/3_Sampling/1_sampling_biased_vs_non_biased.ipynb) is my work from where i came up with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to treat outliers. Outliers can either be generated by **chance** from the data's distribution or can be a result of human **error** (error in measurement, error in data entry, etc.).

- If you consider the outlier to be from the first category, in my opinion you **shouldn't discard** it, in order to take your samples from the **true** distribution of the data.
  Outliers in this category, might indicate a [heavily-skewed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness), or might simply appear due to the nature of the problem (e.g. [King's effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_effect)).
- If you consider it to be an error (e.g. a human height of 3.75m), you **should discard** it as it corrupts the distribution of the data.

In order to determine which category the outliers belongs to, either requires **domain knowledge** (e.g. knowing that human height can't exceed 3m) or requires you to make **assumptions** on the data.